# Strange problem with IO or file system or what?

Tags: files, io, disk

On a SLES 11 SP2 32-bit system I'm seeing a strange problem. It's as if the OS can not open a file from the beginning of the file.

Say I have a file that is 200 lines.  If I `cat` or `more` or `vi` the file, the system just hangs. The process never even starts.  I can tail the same file, but only up to about 100 lines.

These work:

```
$ tail /path/to/file
$ tail -n 25 /path/to/file
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ tail -n 100 /path/to/file
```

Even an `ls` command on a directory with lots of files fails.

There is plenty of disk space.  The file system is read/write.  An `fsck` did do some fixes but the problem still exists.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

**Update:**

I have a file that is 3048 bytes in size.
I can use `tail -c` to read the file in chunks, but as soon as I get close to the actual file size, it hangs again.

These work:

```
$ tail -c 1000 /path/to/file
$ tail -c 2000 /path/to/file
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ tail -c 2750 /path/to/file
```

Comment: Does that happen with a specific file, or with many files? Does anything appear in the system logs (look for recently-modified files in `/var/log`)?

Comment: Any file that has more than 100 lines as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you write files in excess to 100 lines? Sounds like the disk is possibly failing.

Comment: I can create files.  For instance, `mysqldump` can dump a database and `tar` can compress that file into a TGZ.  But I can't `cat` or `more` the file.

Comment: Is this RAID? Is your array degraded? If not, what does `smartctl -a` show about the disk?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with an MTU setting on the router which affected our centralized logging.  The process wouldn't start because logging was trying to push data up to the logging server and the MTU mismatch prevented it from establishing a connection.